# Ancient Greek-Latin and Latin-Ancient Greek books II

Tags: classical-latin, ancient-greek

Is there any book of comparative Ancient Greek-Latin text-based teaching?
(I am talking about a parallel method containing e.g. latin texts' fragments translated in ancient greek with comparative analysis of syntax and grammar and vice versa)

Comment: Can you add more details on what you are after? Is there something in the right direction that falls short somehow? Are there similar things for other pairs of languages?

Comment: I do not know similar books in english. I am just talking about books containing e.g. latin texts' fragments translated in ancient greek with comparative analysis of syntax and grammar and vice versa.

Comment: In other words I mean a method of parallel learning.

Comment: You might want to add that information to the body of the question so it's more visible. I don't know of any textbooks of this nature, but I'd be interested in learning if they do exist.

Answer (score 1):

Not because it is just what is sought by the question, but in order to bring up an alternative to that end as I understand the OP, I think, parallel readings supplemented by grammar sources would be quite helpful, as Tom Hendrickson says in his essay “[Reading Greek in Latin](https://medium.com/in-medias-res/reading-greek-in-latin-939c0e70a8de)”

> Greek literature in Latin translation presents a marvellous
> opportunity for those of us who want to get to know those languages
> better. How would a Latin-speaker render a given idea in idiomatic
> Latin? Just look at the choices that actual Latin translators have
> made.
>
> There are a lot of Latin translations of Greek works, stretching from
> the earliest Latin authors through the modern era. In Late Antiquity,
> Christian authors in the Latin world wrestled with how to translate
> the mountain of Greek scriptures, commentaries, homilies, apologies,
> and invective. The Renaissance saw John Argyropoulos bring Greek
> scholarship to Florence, which resulted in a bloom of translations
> into Latin. Even as late as the nineteenth century, Migne’s
> *Patrologia Graeca* included Latin translations for its many myriad pages of Greek works.

The difficulty may be to access to such translations. There are several directions in the cited essay. Also there's a series under the name *Barriclyn Classics* sold on Amazon kindle store (see, for example, *[Antigone, Electra and Trachiniae: Greek, Latin and English](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00V0U7T3K)*). Nevertheless, it seems it remains to one's own capacity to compile the material.